# HTML Entity Codes to Text

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Does anyone know an easy way in Python to convert a string with HTML entity codes (e.g. `&lt;` `&amp;`) to a normal string (e.g. < &)?

`cgi.escape()` will escape strings (poorly), but there is no `unescape()`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/htmlparser.html) has the functionality in the standard library. It is, unfortunately, undocumented:

(Python2 [Docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/htmlparser.html))

```
>>> import HTMLParser
>>> h= HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
>>> h.unescape('alpha &lt; &beta;')
u'alpha < \u03b2'
```

(Python 3 [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html))

```
>>> import html.parser
>>> h = html.parser.HTMLParser()
>>> h.unescape('alpha &lt; &beta;')
'alpha < \u03b2'
```

[htmlentitydefs](http://docs.python.org/library/htmllib.html#module-htmlentitydefs) is documented, but requires you to do a lot of the work yourself.

If you only need the XML predefined entities (lt, gt, amp, quot, apos), you could use minidom to parse them. If you only need the predefined entities and no numeric character references, you could even just use a plain old string replace for speed.

Comment: +1 I didn't know that function of HTMLParser

Comment: Here's a documented function from the standard library that will convert escaped HTML code to a normal string: http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.utils.html#xml.sax.saxutils.unescape

Comment: In Python 3.4, is was [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape).

Answer (score 12):

I forgot to tag it at first, but I'm using BeautifulSoup.

Digging around in the documentation, I found:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)
```

does it exactly as I was hoping.

Comment: This only works for BeautifulSoup versions pre-BS4. If you are using BS4, you must use a formatter: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters

Comment: it does not work for &amp; Actually, if a string contains '&', BeautifulSoup converts it back to &amp;, which is the opposite of what I was hoping.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built into the Python stdlib to unescape HTML, but there's a short script you can tailor to your needs at http://www.w3.org/QA/2008/04/unescape-html-entities-python.html.

Comment: There is a thing built into the Python stdlib to unescape HTML. See the accepted answer and edit your answer please.

Answer (score 1):

Use [htmlentitydefs](http://docs.python.org/library/htmllib.html#module-htmlentitydefs) module. This my old code, it worked, but I'm sure there is cleaner and more pythonic way to do it:

```
e2c = dict(('&%s;'%k,eval("u'\\u%04x'"%v)) for k, v in htmlentitydefs.name2codepoint.items())
```