# Convert HTML entities to Unicode and vice versa

Tags: python, html, html-entities

How do you convert HTML entities to Unicode and vice versa in Python?

Comment: @Jarret Hardie: Actually, show-and-tell is perfectly fine on SO. From the first entry on the FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq) "It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own programming question". Although, it's also encouraged to look for duplicates as well.

Comment: I am posting questions that I have answered for myself in the past for the benefit of other users searching for similar answers.

Comment: Can also be done without external libraries. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663058/html-entity-codes-to-text/663128#663128

Comment: +1 He is contributing to the dataset.

Comment: This question is wider in scope than then one pointed to by the "duplicate" link: this question also asks for "vice versa", i.e., from  Unicode to HTML entities.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to have [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup
import cgi

def HTMLEntitiesToUnicode(text):
    """Converts HTML entities to unicode.  For example '&amp;' becomes '&'."""
    text = unicode(BeautifulStoneSoup(text, convertEntities=BeautifulStoneSoup.ALL_ENTITIES))
    return text

def unicodeToHTMLEntities(text):
    """Converts unicode to HTML entities.  For example '&' becomes '&amp;'."""
    text = cgi.escape(text).encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
    return text

text = "&amp;, &reg;, &lt;, &gt;, &cent;, &pound;, &yen;, &euro;, &sect;, &copy;"

uni = HTMLEntitiesToUnicode(text)
htmlent = unicodeToHTMLEntities(uni)

print uni
print htmlent
# &, ®, <, >, ¢, £, ¥, €, §, ©
# &amp;, &#174;, &lt;, &gt;, &#162;, &#163;, &#165;, &#8364;, &#167;, &#169;
```

Comment: The BeautifulSoup api has changed. Please see the most recent [doc](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: @hekevintran: Is it possible to print '&#x00A2;, &#x00A3;, &#x00A5;, &#x20AC;, &#x00A7;, &#x00A9;' instead of '¢, £, ¥, €, §, ©'. Any idea?

Comment: This answer is in desperate need of a Python3 update.

Answer (score 111):

As to the "vice versa" (which I needed myself, leading me to find this question, which didn't help, and subsequently [another site which had the answer](http://www.megasolutions.net/python/Unicode-to-HTML-entities-78703.aspx)):

```
u'some string'.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
```

will return a plain string with any non-ascii characters turned into XML (HTML) entities.

Comment: I've forgotten about xmlcharrefreplace and this was very helpful. Any time I need to safely store encoded or non-ascii characters to mysql I find I need to use this method.

Comment: This doesn't work with a string literal containing the unicode character U+2019 HTML entity equivalent &#8217;
Isn't this what the question was asking for (this answer converts ascii which is a subset of unicode)?

    text.decode('utf-8').encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')

Comment: @MikeS It works without problem; `>>> u'\u2019'.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8').encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')` gives `'&#8217;'`

Answer (score 22):

Update for Python 2.7 and BeautifulSoup4

Unescape -- Unicode HTML to unicode with `htmlparser` (Python 2.7 standard lib):

```
>>> escaped = u'Monsieur le Cur&eacute; of the &laquo;Notre-Dame-de-Gr&acirc;ce&raquo; neighborhood'
>>> from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
>>> htmlparser = HTMLParser()
>>> unescaped = htmlparser.unescape(escaped)
>>> unescaped
u'Monsieur le Cur\xe9 of the \xabNotre-Dame-de-Gr\xe2ce\xbb neighborhood'
>>> print unescaped
Monsieur le Curé of the «Notre-Dame-de-Grâce» neighborhood
```

Unescape -- Unicode HTML to unicode with `bs4` (BeautifulSoup4):

```
>>> html = '''<p>Monsieur le Cur&eacute; of the &laquo;Notre-Dame-de-Gr&acirc;ce&raquo; neighborhood</p>'''
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> soup.text
u'Monsieur le Cur\xe9 of the \xabNotre-Dame-de-Gr\xe2ce\xbb neighborhood'
>>> print soup.text
Monsieur le Curé of the «Notre-Dame-de-Grâce» neighborhood
```

Escape -- Unicode to unicode HTML with `bs4` (BeautifulSoup4):

```
>>> unescaped = u'Monsieur le Curé of the «Notre-Dame-de-Grâce» neighborhood'
>>> from bs4.dammit import EntitySubstitution
>>> escaper = EntitySubstitution()
>>> escaped = escaper.substitute_html(unescaped)
>>> escaped
u'Monsieur le Cur&eacute; of the &laquo;Notre-Dame-de-Gr&acirc;ce&raquo; neighborhood'
```

Comment: upvote for showing a standard library solution with no dependencies

Comment: Revisiting I just saw the comment @bobince left on the question pointing to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/663128/1599229). Since `htmlparser` is documented now, and since that comment is not prominent, leaving that part of answer.

Answer (score 17):

As *hekevintran* answer suggests, you may use `cgi.escape(s)` for encoding stings, but notice that encoding of quote is false by default in that function and it may be a good idea to pass the `quote=True` keyword argument alongside your string. But even by passing `quote=True`, the function won't escape single quotes (`"'"`) (Because of these issues the function has been [deprecated](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/cgi.html#cgi.escape) since version 3.2)

It's been suggested to use `html.escape(s)` instead of `cgi.escape(s)`. (New in version 3.2)

Also `html.unescape(s)` has been [introduced in version 3.4](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/html.html#html.unescape).

So in python 3.4 you can:

- Use `html.escape(text).encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace').decode()` to convert special characters to HTML entities.
- And `html.unescape(text)` for converting HTML entities back to plain-text representations.

Comment: In Python 2.7 you can use HTMLParser.unescape(text)

Answer (score 15):

For `python3` use [`html.unescape()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape):

```
import html
s = "&amp;"
u = html.unescape(s)
# &
```

Comment: Simple and sweet.

Answer (score 8):

```
$ python3 -c "
> import html
> print(
>     html.unescape('&amp;&#169;&#x2014;')
> )"
&©—

$ python3 -c "
> import html
> print(
>     html.escape('&©—')
> )"
&amp;©—

$ python2 -c "
> from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
> print(
>     HTMLParser().unescape('&amp;&#169;&#x2014;')
> )"
&©—

$ python2 -c "
> import cgi
> print(
>     cgi.escape('&©—')
> )"
&amp;©—
```

HTML only strictly requires `&` (ampersand) and `<` (left angle bracket / less-than sign) to be escaped. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#data-state

Answer (score 3):

If someone like me is out there wondering why some entity numbers (codes) like `&#153; (for trademark symbol), &#128; (for euro symbol)` are not encoded properly, the reason is in ISO-8859-1 (aka Windows-1252) those characters are not defined.

Also note that, the default character set as of html5 is utf-8 it was ISO-8859-1 for html4

So, we will have to workaround somehow (find & replace those at first)

Reference (starting point) from Mozilla's documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Localizations_and_character_encodings

Answer (score 1):

I used the following function to convert unicode ripped from an xls file into a an html file while conserving the special characters found in the xls file:

```
def html_wr(f, dat):
    ''' write dat to file f as html
        . file is assumed to be opened in binary format
        . if dat is nul it is replaced with non breakable space
        . non-ascii characters are translated to xml       
    '''
    if not dat:
        dat = '&nbsp;'
    try:
        f.write(dat.encode('ascii'))
    except:
        f.write(html.escape(dat).encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace'))
```

hope this is useful to somebody

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import fileinput
import html

for line in fileinput.input():
    print(html.unescape(line.rstrip('\n')))
```