# Unicode encoding in python

Tags: python, unicode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert XML/HTML Entities into Unicode String in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708/convert-xml-html-entities-into-unicode-string-in-python)
>   [Decode HTML entities in Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string)

I am using Python 2.7 and am fairly lost in unicode type. I looked up variety of help files and tutorials on it by I cannot get it actually working in the context I need.
http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html

I have a library with names and it was saved decoded, ex. aaron's
I need to encode the name into a user friendly manner
Seems like basic answer to encoding

```
a ='aaron&#39;s,'
unicode(a)
a.encode('ascii', 'replace')
```

returns:

```
'aaron&#39;s,'
```

Which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: See

 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708/convert-xml-html-entities-into-unicode-string-in-python
 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701704/how-do-you-convert-html-entities-to-unicode-and-vice-versa-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for *HTML entity decoding*, not Unicode (or codec) decoding.

See [Decode HTML entities in Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string) for ways to do this.