# Replace all ascii symbols (other than alphabets) into HTML number in Python

Tags: python, html, ascii

I need to replace all the ascii symbols other than alphabets into HTML number (http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm).
From this post([Convert HTML entities to Unicode and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701704/convert-html-entities-to-unicode-and-vice-versa)), I could use this code, but I still can't get `*` (or maybe many other characters) working.

What could be the solution? Just simple replacements could be the only solution?

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup as bs
>>> import cgi
>>> cgi.escape("<*>").encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')

'&lt;*&gt;'
```

Comment: Why would `*` get replaced? It's not special in this context. There is no [html entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) for `*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague. I will assume that by "alphabets" you mean all characters from a-z and their uppercase variants. Then you can achieve the desired result using a regular expression:

```
>>> f = lambda s: re.sub(r'([^a-zA-Z])', lambda x: '&#{};'.format(ord(x.group(0))), s)
>>> f("<hi>")
'&#60;hi&#62;'
>>> f("<*>")
'&#60;&#42;&#62;'
```

Please note that, without knowing about your special application, this looks like a weird thing to do. There might be a better approach to solve the real underlying problem.