# Python Input Sanitization

Tags: python, forms, validation, input, sanitization

I need to do some very quick-n-dirty input sanitizing and I would like to basically convert all `<, >` to `&lt;, &gt;`.

I'd like to achieve the same results as `'<script></script>'.replace('<', '&lt;').replace('>', '&gt;')` without having to iterate the string multiple times.  I know about `maketrans` in conjunction with `str.translate` (ie. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_translate.htm) but this only converts from 1 char to another char.  In other words, one cannot do something like:

```
inList = '<>'
outList = ['&lt;', '&gt;']
transform = maketrans(inList, outList)
```

Is there a `builtin` function that can do this conversion in a single iteration?

I'd like to use `builtin` capabilities as opposed to external modules.  I already know about `Bleach`.

Comment: Why not just iterate by hand?

Comment: In that case it seems you actually want to particularly encode characters in HTML, please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701704/convert-html-entities-to-unicode-and-vice-versa

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/python-replace-multiple-strings for multiple string replacement in general.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use html.escape() - cgi.escape() is deprecated in Python 3

```
import html
input = '<>&'
output = html.escape(input)
print(output)

&lt;&gt;&amp;
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use `cgi.escape()`

```
import cgi
inlist = '<>'
transform = cgi.escape(inlist)
print transform
```

Output:

```
&lt;&gt;
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html#cgi.escape

> cgi.escape(s[, quote]) Convert the characters '&', '<' and '>' in
>   string s to HTML-safe sequences. Use this if you need to display text
>   that might contain such characters in HTML. If the optional flag quote
>   is true, the quotation mark character (") is also translated; this
>   helps for inclusion in an HTML attribute value delimited by double
>   quotes, as in . Note that single quotes are never
>   translated.

Comment: As mentioned in other comments, this method is deprecated since Python 3.2 (https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/cgi.html#cgi.escape). It suggests using html.escape.

Answer (score 3):

You can define your own function that loops over the string once and replaces any characters you define.

```
def sanitize(input_string):
    output_string = ''
    for i in input_string:
        if i == '>':
            outchar = '&gt;'
        elif i == '<':
            outchar = '&lt;'
        else:
            outchar = i
        output_string += outchar
    return output_string
```

Then calling

```
sanitize('<3 because I am > all of you')
```

yields

```
'&lt;3 because I am &gt; all of you'
```

Comment: do have a look at string.join and list comprehensions!

Comment: Using + with strings is quadratic because it constructs a new string every time.  I *think* CPython can optimize this into a linear operation, but other implementations like PyPy may not be able to.

Comment: IMPORTANT: When rolling your own sanitzer, always use an explicit list.  If any characters are NOT in the set of things you allow either a) raise an error or b) remove it or c) replace with a neutral character of some kind ...

IE:   `else if i in set(string.ascii_letters + string.ascii_digits): ... `