# Python - scraping website with unicode

Tags: python, unicode

I am trying to scrape a site using this code

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    #coding = utf-8
    import urllib, urllib2
    req = urllib2.Request(‘http://some website’)
    req.add_header('User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36')
    f = urllib2.urlopen(req) 
    body = f.read()
    f.close()
```

This is part of the document returned by the read() method

```
    T\u00f3m l\u01b0\u1ee3c di\u1ec5n ti\u1ebfn Th\u01b0\u1ee3ng H\u1ed9i \u0110\u1ed3ng Gi\u00e1m M\u1ee5c v\u1ec1 Gia \u0110\u00ecnh\
```

How can I change the above code to get the result like this?

```
    Tóm lược diễn tiến Thượng Hội Đồng Giám Mục về Gia Đình
```

Thank you.

My issue is solved by using mata's advice. Here the code that works for me. Thank you everyone for helping, especially mata.

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
#coding = utf-8
import urllib, urllib2
req = urllib2.Request(‘http://some website’)
req.add_header('User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36')
f = urllib2.urlopen(req) 
body = f.read().decode('unicode-escape').encode('utf-8')
f.close()
```

Comment: Have you checked similar questions to see if they help? like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701704/convert-html-entities-to-unicode-and-vice-versa)

Comment: python2 wouldn't produce unicode escapes in a string returned by read() if they weren't there literally, so could it be that the document contains unicode escapes (might be JSON)? In that case the `json` module module might be helpful, or try `body.decode('unicode-escape')`

Comment: beautifulsoup is good for this sort of thing

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping. My issue is solved by using mata's advice.

Answer (score 1):

you need to detect the encoding of the page the decode it, try using this lib for the encoding detection http://github.com/chardet/chardet se the usage help and example at http://chardet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html

```
pip install chardet
```

then use it

```
import urllib, urllib2
import chardet  #<- import this lib

req = urllib2.Request(‘http://some website’)
req.add_header('User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36')
f = urllib2.urlopen(req) 
body = f.read()
f.close()

code = chardet.detect(body)           #<- detect the encoding
body = body.decode(code['encoding'])  #<- decode
```

Answer (score 1):

You must detect encoding from page. This info, in most cases, comes in request's header.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#coding = utf-8

import cgi
import urllib2

req = urllib2.Request("http://some website")
req.add_header("User-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36")
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
encoding = f.headers.getparam('charset') # Here, you will detect the page encoding
body = f.read().decode(encoding) # Here you will define which encode use to decode data.
f.close()
```

There are another ways to get same result, but I just adapted to your approach.