# How do I encode specific characters to HTML in python

Tags: python, html

I'm scraping Wikipedia using BeautifulSoup4 in Python.

```
data = urllib2.urlopen(wikiurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
```

I then use

```
for link in soup.find_all('p'):
   completehtml = completehtml + str(link)
```

To get the HTML for a few paragraphs (The for loop has a break condition using a counter that counts the number of paragraphs and then breaks if they reach the limit)

Now after this data has been scraped. I need to enter it at a website online. (I need to enter it using the HTML which is scrapped). The problem is that some of the characters such as en-dash are not in proper HTML i.e coded in HTML, which is causing symbols to appear instead.

They print out fine in Python. But when I use methods such as pyautogui or the ActionChains class to send keys and thereby enter them using the scrapped string, they are entered as symbols.

How do I fix this. Looking for a solution in Python.

***EDIT:***
Okay, so the main issue is when non-ascii characters are in the scrapped html. 
They're decoded to 'latin-1' when they're copied to clipboard or entered using the send keys method by python.

***EDIT:***
Need to convert certain HTML entities to unicode then turn them back into HTML after replacing certain unicode substirngs.

Comment: Do you need to unescape the HTML? I.e., replace `&copy;` with © ?

Comment: No the opposite, so when an en-dash is entered. I need it as `&ndash;` instead of `–`

Comment: Use search-and-replace. [Here](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) is a list.

Comment: `html.escape()` for Python 3. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/ for more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the solution to this post would give you what you need:
[Convert HTML entities to Unicode and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701704/convert-html-entities-to-unicode-and-vice-versa)

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you so much.