# Python replace text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hello I have trouble with replacing all texts from HTML. I wanted to make a censure with BeautifulSoup but it doesn't replace a content and I got error when I print contents (not all texts from HTML were printed)

```
words = ['Shop','Car','Home','Generic','Elements']
page = urllib.urlopen("html1/index.html").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
for i in texts :
    if i == words :
       i = '***'
    print i
```

Anyone know how to fix it?

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "replacing.py", line 28, in <module>
print i
File "F:\Python\Python27\lib\encodings\cp852.py", line 12, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 25: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Would you mind including a small sample of text that *wont* print in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two major issues here.  The first is an encoding issue, where you are trying to print a non-printable character. For that you can use answers found in:

[UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode - character maps to <undefined>, print function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630288/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-character-maps-to-undefined)

Or, for a more in depth explanation:

[Python, Unicode, and the Windows console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419/python-unicode-and-the-windows-console) (Now that I look at this more it's probably outdated, but still an interesting read).

However, you also have a logic problem with your code.

```
if i == words:
```

This line doesn't check if `i` is *found* in words, but instead compares `i` to a list of words, which isn't what you want.  I would recommend making the following changes:

```
words = {'Shop','Car','Home','Generic','Elements'}

for i in texts:
    if i in words:
        i = '***'
```

Converting `words` to a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) allows for average `O(1)` lookup, and using `if i in words` checks if `i` is found in words.

Comment: I found that error in iteration and I fix it. I have one question about replacing a string with blank spaces, how is the correct way to replace a simple words when string has a words with blank spaces, for example : 
input : "My new car is good" 
output: "My new *** is good"

Comment: You could use `split()` to split into individual words and then replace using a list comprehension like this: https://repl.it/repls/PoorCorruptCarriers

Comment: Thank You for fix ;) Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of the characters you are trying to print is not found in the codec python uses to print messages. I.e. you have the data for a character but you don't know what symbol it should be and so you can't print it. A simple conversion of the HTML to a unicode format should solve your problem.

Good question on how to do that:

[Convert HTML entities to Unicode and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701704/convert-html-entities-to-unicode-and-vice-versa)