# How can i change string encoding?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I need to change the encoding of language specific characters during a conversion of an csv to xml. As example:

I allready tried around with enconding option but i can't achieve what i want

```
un Plan d’action
```

should be:

```
un Plan d&#8217;action
```

Comment: This may be helpful in addition to the previously linked answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24643425/9794932

Comment: If you properly use a proper XML library, this should be taken care of for you automatically.