# How can I change '>' to '&gt;' and '&gt;' to '>'?

Tags: python

```
print u'&lt;'
```

How can I print `<`

```
print '>'
```

How can I print `&gt;`

Comment: I don't do Python, but those are called "HTML entities". If you poke around using that new keyword in Google, you may find enough information: http://www.google.com/search?q=python+html+entities

Comment: That's not likely to be enough, BalusC. The OP makes it clear in his profile that explanations in English are difficult to understand, he wants **code**. *Consider that the QUESTION is in the form of code*

Comment: yeah, BalusC, send him teh c0dez

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use `HTMLParser` module to [decode html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663058/html-entity-codes-to-text):

```
>>> import HTMLParser
>>> h= HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
>>> h.unescape('alpha &lt; &beta;')
u'alpha < \u03b2'
```

To escape HTML, [cgi module is fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061697/whats-the-easiest-way-to-escape-html-in-python):

```
>>> cgi.escape(u'<a>bá</a>').encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
'&lt;a&gt;b&#225;&lt;/a&gt;
```

Comment: +1 for HTMLParser and the great links.