# Making beautiful soup play nice with handlebars

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, handlebars.js

I am making a script to refactor template-enhanced html.

I'd like beautifulsoup to print verbatim any code inside `{{` `}}` without transforming `>` or other symbols into html entities.

It needs to split a file with many templates into many files, each with one template.

Spec:  `splitTemplates templates.html templateDir` must:

1. read templates.html
2. for each `<template name="xxx">contents {{ > directive }}</template>`, write this template to file `templateDir/xxx`

Code snippet:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(open(filename,"r"))
for t in soup.children:
    if t.name=="template":
        newfname = dirname+"/"+t["name"]+ext
        f = open(newfname,"w")
        # note f.write(t) fails as t is not a string -- prettify works
        f.write(t.prettify())
        f.close()
```

Undesired behavior:

`{{ > directive }}` becomes `{{ &gt; directive }}` but needs to be preserved as `{{ > directive }}`

Update:  `f.write(t.prettify(formatter=None))` sometimes preserves the `>` and sometimes changes it to `&gt;`.  This seems to be the most obvious change, not sure why it changes some `>` but not others.

Solved:  Thanks to Hai Vu and also https://stackoverflow.com/a/663128/103081

```
    import HTMLParser
    U = HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(open(filename,"r"))
    for t in soup.children:
        if t.name=="template":
            newfname = dirname+"/"+t["name"]+ext
            f = open(newfname,"w")
            f.write(U(t.prettify(formatter=None)))
            f.close()
```

See Also: https://gist.github.com/DrPaulBrewer/9104465

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unescape the HTML contents. To do that, use the HTMLParser module. This is not my original idea. I took it from:

[How can I change '>' to '&gt;' and '&gt;' to '>'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977900/how-can-i-change-to-gt-and-gt-to)