# From escaped html -> to regular html? - Python

Tags: python, html, escaping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I used BeautifulSoup to handle XML files that I have collected through a REST API.

The responses contain HTML code, but BeautifulSoup escapes all the HTML tags so it can be displayed nicely.

Unfortunately I need the HTML code.

---

How would I go on about transforming the escaped HTML into proper markup?

---

Help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: one of many duplicates:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663058/html-entity-codes-to-text

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you want [xml.sax.saxutils.unescape](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.utils.html?highlight=xml#xml.sax.saxutils.unescape) from the Python standard library.

E.g.:

```
>>> from xml.sax import saxutils as su
>>> s = '&lt;foo&gt;bar&lt;/foo&gt;'
>>> su.unescape(s)
'<foo>bar</foo>'
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't handle all characters. For example, ``su.unescape('&quot;')`` doesn't work.

Comment: You can escape other characters by specifying them in a dictionary as the second parameter to `unescape`. For example: `su.unescape(s, {'&quot;':'"'})`

Comment: This worked for me ...Thanks...Let see for other items

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) module?

It has a method `unquote()` that might suit your needs.

Edit: on second thought, (and more reading of your question) you might just want to just use `string.replace()`

Like so:

```
string.replace('&lt;','<')
string.replace('&gt;','>')
```

Comment: Why would you bother with coding the different replace steps (for lt, gt, amp) when the saxutils.unescape wraps them all up for you?-)  Plus, remember: the replace call doesn't alter the string, it builds a new string. Your code snippet, as given, is a slow no-op!-)