# How do I get the text contents of a textarea with webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to get the contents of a [textarea](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.7) in an HTML form using [webdriver in Python](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PythonBindings).

I'm getting the text, but newlines are missing. The [selenium docs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) are pretty much useless; they say:

> class selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement(parent, id_)
>
> [...]
>
> text: Gets the text of the element.

I'm currently doing the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver

# open the browser and web site
b = webdriver.Firefox()
b.get('http://www.example.com')

# get the textarea element
textbox = b.find_element_by_name('textbox')

# print the contents of the textarea
print(repr(textbox.text))
```

This prints the representation of a Python unicode string of the textarea's contents, except all the newlines have been replaced by spaces. Doh!

Not sure if I'm facing a text encoding issue, selenium/webdriver bug (couldn't find it in the tracker), or user error.

Is there a different way to do this?

**EDIT**: I just gave Chrome a try... works fine. I reported a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2956) to selenium's issue tracker. Sam's workaround (the accepted answer below) works in Firefox with one caveat: symbols are converted to HTML entity codes in the returned string. This is [no big deal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2474992/182642).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a workaround you can try using ExecuteScript to get the innerHtml.  I am not a python guy, but here it is in C#:

```
IWebElement element = ...
String returnText = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriver).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML", element).ToString();
```

Comment: Great suggestion. This works almost perfectly. The only issue is that symbols are translated into their HTML entity codes in the resulting string. i.e. `<`  becomes `&lt;`, and so on. I cast a few low-level Python spells and mitigated that issue.

Comment: For reference, the equivalent Python code is `text = my_web_driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].innerHTML", textarea_element)`.

Comment: In Python, `xml.sax.saxutils.unescape(text)` un-escapes the `&`, `<` and `>` entities.

Answer (score 7):

I have just got attribute value of tag textarea. Below is a sample of Java code.

```
WebElement textarea = driver.findElement(By.id("xf-1242"));         
String text = textarea.getAttribute("value");
log.debut(text);
```

I am using Chrome driver, and above code put a text (XML in my case) with newlines in the log. 
I got the idea from http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_textarea.asp

Jan

Answer (score 0):

In Python get the element first, and after get the attribute value, function in python get_attribute('value').

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_textarea"
driver.get(URL)
driver.switch_to.frame("iframeResult")
# get the textarea element by tag name
textarea = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('textarea')

# print the attribute of the textarea
print(textarea.get_attribute('value'))
print(textarea.get_attribute('rows'))
print(textarea.get_attribute('cols'))
```